# Object to continue moving after one go

Tags: arrays, processing

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this program.

I need to make the ball that is going horizontally start moving again and then shoot another ball that is going vertically. How can I make this happen over and over again, rather than it stopping after one go?

Also, how can I make the ball launching done by any key on the keyboard rather than the touchpad?

This is my program:

```java
    int xPos =200;
    int yPos =700;
    int xDir=3;   // SPEED
    
    float ball2X;
    float ball2Y;
    float ball2Speed=5;
    boolean ball2Exist = false;
    
    void setup () {  
    size (1280, 960);
    }
    
    void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill (255, 200, 200);
    rect (0, 550, width, height);
    fill (225);
    
    //Player(ball)
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, 140, 140);
    fill (255, 200, 200);
      xPos=xPos+xDir;
      if (xPos>width-20 || xPos<20)
      {
        xDir=-xDir;
      }
      
      if(ball2Exist)
      {
        fill (255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(ball2X, ball2Y, 70, 70);
        ball2Y -= ball2Speed;
      }
    }
    
    void mouseClicked() {
      if(xDir!=0) // first click
      xDir = 0;
      else // second click
      {
        ball2X = xPos;
        ball2Y = yPos;
        ball2Exist = true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the ball launching done by pressing a key, you can use the [`keyPressed()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) function in the same way that you used the [`mouseClicked()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) function. In order to make the horizontal ball continue moving after launching a ball, you can just set the ball's speed `xDir` to its old value. To ensure that it continues going in the same direction you should use a variable to store its current value before you set it to 0, then you can set xDir to this value after launching the ball. In order to have multiple red balls you want to store a list of ball information so that you can draw multiple balls at the same time and in order to this effectively, you probably want to create a `Ball` class.

In the following program, I made a ball class to encapsulate all of the ball drawing, and I used [`PVectors`](https://processing.org/tutorials/pvector/) to deal with the x and y corrdinates for position and speed.

```java
// Horizontal ball
Ball mainBall;
// List of red balls
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

void setup () {  
  size (1280, 960);
  
  //Create main ball
  mainBall = new Ball(200, 700, 3, 0, 140, color(255, 200, 200));
  
  // Create list of balls
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill (255, 200, 200);
  rect (0, 550, width, height);
  
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  //If the main ball collides with edge of window, reverse speed
  mainBall.collisionUpdate();
  //Draw the main ball
  mainBall.drawBall();
  
  //Create arraylist to store balls to get removed from the list
  ArrayList<Ball> toRemove = new ArrayList<Ball>();
  
  // For every ball
  for(Ball ball : balls){
    ball.drawBall();
    
    //If the ball is off the screen need to remove it
    if(ball.isNotVisible()){
      toRemove.add(ball);
    }
  }
  
  // Remove all the non-visible balls
  balls.removeAll(toRemove);
}

void launch(){
  // Add a new ball to the list
  balls.add(new Ball(mainBall.position.x, mainBall.position.y, 0, -5, 70, color(255, 0, 0)));
}

void mouseClicked() {
  launch();
}

void keyPressed(){
  launch();
}

// Ball class
class Ball{
  PVector position;
  PVector speed;
  float diameter;
  color c;
  
  Ball(float x, float y, float xSpeed, float ySpeed, float _diameter, color _c){
    position = new PVector(x, y);
    speed = new PVector(xSpeed, ySpeed);
    diameter = _diameter;
    c = _c;
  }
  
  void drawBall(){
    fill(c);
    circle(position.x, position.y, diameter);
    // Update position of ball
    position.add(speed);
  }

  void collisionUpdate(){
    if(position.x < diameter/2 || position.x > width-diameter/2 || position.y < diameter/2 || position.y > height-diameter/2 ){
      //Reverse speed
      speed.mult(-1);
    }
  }
  
  // Return true or false if the ball is off the screen
  boolean isNotVisible(){
     return position.x > width+diameter || position.x < -diameter || position.y > height+diameter || position.y < -diameter;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

To make the balls decelerate and ricochet off the window boundaries. I also used a random function to randomise the speed and the rate at which the balls decelerate.

```java
// Horizontal ball
Ball mainBall;
// List of red balls
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

PVector oldSpeed;

void setup () {  
  size (1280, 960);
  
  //Create main ball
  mainBall = new Ball(200, 700, 3, 0, 140, color(255, 200, 200));
  
  // Create list of balls
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill (255, 200, 200);
  rect (0, 550, width, height);
  
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  //If the main ball collides with edge of window, reverse speed
  mainBall.collisionUpdate();
  //Draw the main ball
  mainBall.drawBall();
  
  //Create arraylist to store balls to get removed from the list
  ArrayList<Ball> toRemove = new ArrayList<Ball>();
  
  // For every ball
  for(Ball ball : balls){
    // Balls bounce within the screen
    ball.collisionUpdate();
    
    // Slow the speed of the ball
    ball.slowSpeed(random(0.98,0.999));
    
    ball.drawBall();
    
    //If the ball is off the screen need to remove it
    if(ball.isNotVisible()){
      toRemove.add(ball);
    }
  }
  
  // Remove all the non-visible balls
  balls.removeAll(toRemove);
}

void launch(){
  if(!mainBall.isStationary()){
    oldSpeed = mainBall.speed;
    mainBall.setSpeed(0, 0);
  }else{
    // Add a new ball to the list
    balls.add(new Ball(mainBall.position.x, mainBall.position.y, 0, random(-8, -5), 70, color(255, 0, 0)));
    //Make the main ball move again
    mainBall.setSpeed(oldSpeed);
  }
}

void mouseClicked(){
  launch();
}

void keyPressed(){
  launch();
}

// Ball class
class Ball{
  PVector position;
  PVector speed;
  float diameter;
  color c;
  
  Ball(float x, float y, float xSpeed, float ySpeed, float _diameter, color _c){
    position = new PVector(x, y);
    speed = new PVector(xSpeed, ySpeed);
    diameter = _diameter;
    c = _c;
  }
  
  void drawBall(){
    fill(c);
    circle(position.x, position.y, diameter);
    // Update position of ball
    position.add(speed);
  }
  
  void setSpeed(float xSpeed, float ySpeed){
    speed = new PVector(xSpeed, ySpeed);
  }
  
  void setSpeed(PVector _speed){
    speed = _speed;
  }
  
  boolean isStationary(){
    return speed.x == 0 && speed.y == 0;
  }

  void collisionUpdate(){
    if(position.x < diameter/2 || position.x > width-diameter/2 || position.y < diameter/2 || position.y > height-diameter/2 ){
      //Reverse speed
      speed.mult(-1);
    }
  }
  
  void slowSpeed(float deceleration){
      if(speed.mag() < 0.5){
          speed = new PVector(0, 0);
      }else{
          speed.mult(deceleration);
      }
  }
  
  // Return true or false if the ball is off the screen
  boolean isNotVisible(){
     return position.x > width+diameter || position.x < -diameter || position.y > height+diameter || position.y < -diameter;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great! Just one more thing If I would want the mini balls to stay on the screen after launch what would need to be changed in the code?

Comment: @Prabs No worries. Did you mean bounce off the edges? If that's the case then just before `ball.drawBall();` insert the line `ball.collisionUpdate();`.

Comment: Okay, thank you ill give that a go! However more as in when the mini ball is launched it slowly just stops on the screen at a random position in the top half of the screen.

Comment: @Prabs So you want the balls to lose speed as they are launched? You will need to create a function in the ball class to slow the speed of the ball. See the post edit.