# object releases another smaller object?

Tags: processing

Can anyone help me?

So, I'm supposed to have a ball that is moving horizontally, such that every time I press the mouse, a ball would get shoot vertically, then slows down due to friction. The vertical ball would stay in the old position but the player would reset.

How do I go about doing that without using classes?

Here my code so far:

```java
boolean circleupdatetostop = true;
float x = 100;

float yshot = 880;

float speedshot =  random(4,10);
float speedx = 6;


void setup() {
 size(1280,960); 
}

void draw() {
 background(255);
  
 stroke(0);
 fill(0);
 circle(x,880,80);
 
   if (x > width || x < 0 ) {
   speedx = speedx * -1;
   }
   
   if (circleupdatetostop) {
   x = x + speedx;
   }
  
 if (circleupdatetostop == false) {
   float locationx = x;
   stroke(0);
   fill(255,0,255);
   circle(locationx,yshot,30);
   yshot = yshot - speedshot; 
} 
}

void mousePressed () {
  circleupdatetostop = !circleupdatetostop;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you meant, but you could achieve shooting multiple balls by using `ArrayList` as well as processing's [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) to better handle the x and y coordinate pairs. If you wanted to look at classes, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380256/object-to-continue-moving-after-one-go/67388511#67388511).

```java
import java.util.*;

// Whether the ball is moving or not
boolean circleupdatetostop = true;

// Information about the main_ball
PVector position = new PVector(100, 880);
PVector speed = new PVector(6, 0);
float diameter = 80;

// Information about the sot balls
ArrayList<PVector> balls_loc = new ArrayList<PVector>();
ArrayList<PVector> balls_speed = new ArrayList<PVector>();
float diameter_shot = 30;
float friction = 0.994;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 960);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  circle(position.x, position.y, diameter);

  // Remember to consider the radius of the ball when bouncing off the edges
  if (position.x + diameter/2 > width || position.x - diameter/2 < 0 ) {
    speed.mult(-1);
  }

  if (circleupdatetostop) {
    position.add(speed);
  }
  
  // Cycle through the list updating their speed and draw each ball
  for (int i = 0; i<balls_loc.size(); i++) {
    balls_speed.get(i).mult(friction+random(-0.05, 0.05));
    balls_loc.get(i).add(balls_speed.get(i));

    stroke(0);
    fill(255, 0, 255);
    circle(balls_loc.get(i).x, balls_loc.get(i).y, diameter_shot);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  // Add a new ball to be drawn
  if(circleupdatetostop){
    balls_loc.add(new PVector(position.x, position.y));
    balls_speed.add(new PVector(0, random(-4, -10)));
  }
  circleupdatetostop = !circleupdatetostop;
}
```

Comment: Great use of PVector and ArrayList: makes the code much more succint and readable (compared to for example using float arrays and no PVectors) (+1). Also great attention to detail (e.g. taking ball dimensions into account when bouncing at the edges)